# My command javac does not show any result

Tags: java, javac

I can see the version of my java site as well as javac:

```
➜  intro java --version
openjdk 13.0.2 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
➜  intro javac --version
javac 13.0.2
```

In the current directory(intro), I have an Account.java, as well as classes.java

**Account.java:**

```
package intro;

public class Account {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name)
    {   
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args) {       
        System.out.println("Printing the name here");
    }
}
```

**classes.java:**

```
package intro;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class classes {  
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Account myAccount = new Account();
        System.out.printf("Initial name is: %s%n", myAccount.getName());
    }
}
```

I want to run the classes class, which uses methods from Account.java, and when I type the command bellow, nothing prints in the prompt.

```
➜  intro javac Account.java classes.java
➜  intro
```

EDITED: from my current directory I see the files am trying to execute if I run the ls command:

```
➜  intro ls
Account.class  Account.java   classes.class  classes.java   
welcome1.class welcome1.java
```

How do I run the classes.java via the prompt?

Comment: try "java intro.classes"

Answer (score 0):

javac will just compile the classes for you. Once you run

```
`javac Account.java classes.java`
```

You will get the .class files created. Now you should run the class file using the command

```
java classes
```

Comment: The class is named `intro.classes`, not `classes`.

Comment: Perhaps I dont know how to use eclipse yet, but I used IntelliJ and ran: javac Account.java AccountTest.java in its console, then did javac *.java. After I managed to run the classes.java file

Comment: Since the package name is intro, try running 'java intro.classes'